# Calculating working hours of employees using time stamps

Tags: php, mysql

I have FOUR columns in the database which includes the employees name , time stamp of date and time combined which shows the time in and time out of the employees. the time out gets entered in the next row after the time in, Each employee gets in and gets out many times in a day, But i have to consider the first time in and the last time out of each employee and find the difference between time to calculate the total working hours of each employee. The database is as given below. Can anyone please help me on this

```
E Name              Turnstile In        Turnstile Out               Combine
Abhijit K T         SP Turnstile 03 In                              2015-01-01 08:08:36
Abhijit K T         SP Turnstile 03 In                              2015-01-02 08:33:52
Abhijit K T                             SP Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-01 18:22:44
Abhijit K T         SP Turnstile 03 In                              2015-01-01 18:23:00
Abhijit K T                             SP Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-02 19:17:08
Abhilash S M                            SE Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-02 12:08:08
Abhilash S M        SE Turnstile 01 In                              2015-01-02 12:13:20
Abhilash S M                            SE Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-02 13:07:20
Abhilash S M        SE Turnstile 02 In                              2015-01-02 13:13:32
Abhilash S M                            SE Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-02 13:13:24
Abhilash S M                            SE Turnstile 03 Out         2015-01-02 14:44:44
Abhilash S M        SE Turnstile 01 In                              2015-01-02 14:50:16
Abhilash S M                            SE Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-02 16:32:24
Abhilash S M        SE Turnstile 01 In                              2015-01-02 16:37:28
Abhilash S M        SP Turnstile 03 In                              2015-01-02 08:33:32
Abhilash S M                            SE Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-02 18:20:20
Abhilash S M        SE Turnstile 01 In                              2015-01-02 18:20:28
Abhilash S M        SP Turnstile 03 In                              2015-01-02 18:25:44
Abhilash S M                            SP Turnstile 03 Out         2015-01-02 18:28:24
Abhilash S M        SP Turnstile 03 In                              2015-01-01 10:27:40
Abhilash S M                            SE Turnstile 01 Out         2015-01-01 12:21:56
```

Comment: Ok, so see the MIN and MAX aggregating functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works for me

```
select Name,MIN(Combine) InTime,MAX(Combine) OutTime
from licensekeysubscription
group by Name,date(Combine)
```